# pandas: grouping according to two criteria, one of which is a count

Tags: numpy, pandas

I am trying to understand what I can do with pandas, and specifically with the `groupby` facility. 
My Numpy array has pairs of unix timestamps and values.

```
[[  1.40170249e+09   9.00000000e+01]
 [  1.40170249e+09   9.10000000e+01]
 [  1.40170249e+09   9.20000000e+01]
 ..., 
 [  1.41149703e+09   1.09000000e+02]
 [  1.41149703e+09   1.06000000e+02]
 [  1.41149703e+09   1.06000000e+02]]
```

My goal is to bin the values of the second column into 25 bins (`binArray = np.linspace(0, 250, num=25)`), and then group the bin distribution by date. The result, in my imagination, should be a 2d array indexed by date and by decadic bin. What might be the best way to do that?

Comment: What do you want to calculate for each group? Can you give a small example desired output?

Comment: the final output would be a stacked bar chart, with each segment of the stack (on the ordinate) representing the count() of values in each bin, and the abscissa showing time values (e.g. days).

Comment: How is the desired output different than [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26223075/190597)?

Comment: In yesterday's puzzle, the abscissa showed the values and the series showed the times. I tried to transpose the matrix, but that led to nowhere. Groupby by two columns (at least the way I attempted it) also did not work.

Comment: If you are grouping by both columns, a natural way to compute the histogram would be to use `numpy.histogram2d` or, to plot it, [`plt.hist2d`](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/hist2d_log_demo.html). Is that the type of plot you are looking for? It's not shown in the example, but both functions allow you to specify bin edge locations, not just the number of bins.

Comment: I tried rp_obj = df.groupby(df.date.map(lambda x: time.strftime('%Y-%m', x)),df['val']) but I get "TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed"